# How can I create an entity by using generic repository pattern

Tags: generics, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, interface, swagger-ui

I used a generic repository

```cs
interface IGenericRepository<T> where T:class
```

One of data access method is this post method
`Task<T> AddEntityAsync(T Entity)`, I also created add Dto class  for each entity, I gets the relationship In my model in swagger because I don't know how to use dto in generic repository or am I going to use data access method for each entity whenever dto is involved?

I have tried to use dto argument in the add method of d Igeneric repository

Comment: Add `new()` to generic constraint `where T:class, new()`.

Comment: Just to let you know, an additional (generic) repository layer in combination with EF is widely discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic method to create an instance of one entity:

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```